# Indicator Applet Session Log Out Dialog

Tags: 10.10, indicator

I'm trying to create a user profile for 10.10 and my last step is to create a log out button for the desktop.  I managed to find a simple command for a launcher to execute the log out prompt.  Unfortunately, along with an option to log out, there is also an option to switch user.  For my purposes, giving an option to switch the user is not desired. I have tried everything possible to disable user switching but it does not seem to effect the ability to click the switch user option in the log out dialog box.

What I would really like to use is the log out option that the Indicator Applet Session uses.  Clicking log out from the applet does not give the option to switch user.  Is there any way to take whatever command the applet is using and create a launcher for the desktop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact dialog Indicator Session uses
is this: `/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper`

So you can simply add a custom launcher to your panel like so:

[image]

[image: Screenshot of the Log Out Dialog]

Comment: Awesome, that was just what I was looking for!